# Обобщенный тип и неявное\явное указание типа

Tags: c#, методы, generics

К примеру имеется два метода, которые выглядят достаточно тривиально,но возникает вопрос,можно ли назвать их следующим образом:

```
// Обобщенный тип с неявным указанием типа, и соответственно 
// так писать можно(никаких синтаксическим ошибок в коде нет)
void Method(T arg);
```

и такой

```
void Method<T>(T arg); // Обобщенный тип с явным указанием типа
```

То бишь, по сути, оба метода идентичны (и соответственно являются **Обобщенными** или же все таки в первом случае,мы не можем сказать, что метод обобщенный(невзирая на то,что у него есть параметризованный аргумент)?

**UPD**
Забыл уточнить момент,что выше перечисленные методы находятся в обобщенном интерфейсе или классе, т.е.

```
interface IFly<T>
{
    void Method<T>(T arg); //так
    void Method(T arg); // или так
}
```

Comment: первый вариант - ошибка синтаксиса, если только у тебя нет типа T

Comment: в случае когда `void Method<T>(T arg);` внутри `interface IFly<T>`, `T` у метода никак не связан с `T` у интерфейса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обобщенными могут быть:

- Классы и структуры
- Отдельные методы

В первом случае мы можем так указать, только если сам класс, к которому принадлежит метод, является обобщенным и содержит заполнитель (параметр типа) T:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    public void Method(T arg)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Во втором случае у вас обобщенный метод:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void GenericMethod<T>(T arg)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Если к методу в обобщенном классе добавить свои заполнители с таким же названием как у класса, это может привести к путанице и затруднить чтение кода.

Возьмем приведенный выше класс `MyGenericClass`. Мы можем создать его объект и вызвать метод:

```
var obj = new MyGenericClass<int>();
obj.Method(5);
```

В данном случае метод отработает так, как мы и ожидаем. Ничего кроме `int` в метод передать не получится, иначе возникнет ошибка времени компиляции.

Теперь дополнительно параметризируем сам метод:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    public void GenericMethod<T>(T arg)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Поведение метода стало не очевидным:

```
var obj = new MyGenericClass<int>();
obj.Method("blabla"); // Ошибки времени компиляции не возникнет
                      // т.к. будет неявно использоваться обобщенный тип метода
```

Comment: Нет,речь не об этом.
Видимо я упустил этот момент в описании вопроса. Оно и понятно,что пример базируется на классе<T>(твой первый вариант).
Вот в контексте этого класса,они считаются  идентичными,и соответственно явное\неявное указание типа параметра Т?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: При чем тут безопасность-то? Обычное переопределение идентификатора во вложенной области видимости, никаких нарушений безопасности от такого не появляется.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, попытался объяснить, что не стоит так делать, т.к. это может вызвать путаницу у того, кто будет использовать метод. Сейчас понял, что ответил немного не по теме. Подскажите, в таких случаях лучше убирать ответ или оставить?

Comment: @Skrim зависит от того, нравится ли он вам самому :)

Comment: @Skrim понял,благодарю,это и интересовало. Значит,такая записаь как var obj = new MyGenericClass<int>();  
obj.Method<string>("blabla"); - избыточна,ибо неявно приведет тип параметра к string.

Comment: Рекомендуется всегда явно указывать тип, это облегчит ознакомление с кодом тем, кто будет видеть его впервые. Для метода будет использоваться тип метода, а не класса, указываете вы его или нет, т.к. метод обобщен. Т.е. тип метода будет перекрывать тип класса.

Answer (score 7):

Если у вас есть такой код:

```
interface IFly<T>
{
    void Method<T>(T arg); //так
    void Method(T arg); // или так
}
```

То здесь второе объявление T перекрывает первое. На самом деле, приведенный вами код эквивалентен следующему:

```
interface IFly<A>
{
    void Method<B>(B arg); //так
    void Method(A arg); // или так
}
```

Обычно подобное перекрытие является ошибкой, потому что *зачем-то ведь параметр типа был объявлен*. К примеру, код ниже не скомпилируется из-за несоответствия типов:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    T value;

    public void SetValue<T>(T arg) {
        value = arg; // ошибка компиляции
    }
}
```

Кстати, два уровня перекрытия идентификаторов - не предел. Не делайте так:

```
class Foo<T> {
    class Bar<T> {
        class Baz<T> {
            void Method<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

В примере выше все 4 буквы T обозначают разные типы.

Comment: Имелось ввиду,либо в методе есть такой метод void Method(T arg),или же присутствует инная форма записи метода void Method<T>(T arg), т.е. одно из двух.
Мне казалось что эти записи идентичны и, вторая форма(void Method<T>(T arg) это по сути такая же,как и первая,только с избыточной информацией в виде списка параметра Типа.

Comment: @CSharpUser я понял что вы имели в виду. Нет, эти формы не идентичны и я написал почему.