# EF множественные CRUD

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть несколько моделей и для них BusinessContext в котором описаны CRUD операции. По сути они одни, только меняются таблицы

```
public void Create(Client Client)
        {
            _context.Clients.Add(Client);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(Client Client)
        {
            var entity = _context.Clients.Find(Client.Id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("Объект не найден. Обработка этого исключения находится на стадии разработки");
            }

            _context.Entry(Client).CurrentValues.SetValues(Client);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Remove(Client Client)
        {
            _context.Clients.Remove(Client);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Можно ли как-то их модифицировать, что-бы процедура сама определяла в какой таблице работать? Т.е. если я `Crete(Client);` подал, то выполнится создание в таблице `Clients`, а если `Create(Visit)` то в таблице `Visits`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать обобщенный класс с заготовками CRUD.

Класс Crud:

```
public class Crud<T> : IDisposable where T: BaseModel 
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public Crud()
    {
        _context = new DbContext();
    }

    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public virtual void Create(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        var dbEntity = _context.Set<T>().Find(entity.Id);
        if (dbEntity == null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Объект не найден. Обработка этого исключения находится на стадии разработки");
        }

        _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Remove(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Также тут используется класс `BaseModel` в котором будет одно поле `Id` и от которого мы будем наследовать модели. Это нужно для того, чтобы иметь возможность обращаться к идентификатору сущности внутри класса `Crud` (в методе `Update`).

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

---

Еще можете почитать про паттерн репозиторий [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php).

В дополнение к ответу @sp7, почему лучше не создавать своих репозиториев поверх ORM - вышла [хорошая статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/335856/) на эту тему.

Comment: А для получения всех записей из таблицы, можно сделать универсальный метод?

Comment: Да, добавил метод `GetAll()`

Comment: Только у меня работает если указать `GetAll<T>()`

Comment: Должно работать и так как указано в ответе. В данном случае будет использоваться параметр класса, который задается при его инициализации `var crud = new Crud<User>();`. Если же сделать обобщенным сам метод `GetAll<T>()`, то понадобится указывать параметр `T` при каждом вызове метода. Можете почитать про обобщения [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php)

Comment: Дополнение: во втором случае все же указывать параметр метода при каждом вызове не обязательно. Однако это может привести к неоднозначному поведению метода. Смотрите [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606382/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0/606387#606387)

Answer (score 2):

Для решения вашей задачи можно воспользоваться методом `DbContext.Set<T>()`. Например, обобщенный метод, который добавляет сущность в БД может выглядеть так:

```
class DbManager
{
     private DbContext _context;

     public DbManager()
     {
          _context = new EfDbContext();
     }

     public void Create<T>(T entity) where T : class
     {
         // Лишние проверки удалены что бы не загромождать код.
         _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
         _context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Аналогично реализуются методы удаления и обновления.

---

P.S. Вместо лирического отступления.

В целом я бы вам не советовал реализовывать паттерны `Repository` и `Unit of Work` для `EF`, которыми так пестрит интернет, поскольку `EF` и так их реализует из коробки ([тыц](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)).

Где:

- `DbContext` - это реализация `Unit of Work`.
- `DbSet` - реализация `Repository`.